# clearing rails cache dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on rails application , in which i am using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.8. My application is running quite fine in development environment, which includes creating tables from the application and accessing them.

But when i start my application in production environment in which caching is enabled, every thing is working fine , i am not able to access the table which i am creating using my application. I am able to access these tables after restarting the server, which is a pain.

I am searching for a way where i can clear the cache whenever new table get created, can you please help me to clear the cache dynamically.

Thanks
Naveen Kumar Madipally

Comment: Rails 3.0.8 has the YAML/XML remote code execution vulnerbaility. see - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-security/61bkgvnSGTQ- You have patched it for that haven't you?

Answer (score 0):

this will decrease your performance in production but what you can do is fo to `production.rb` file and check the blow lines

```
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

i guess it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The one workaround would be to do this in your environments/production.rb (which is not at all recommended on production)

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

Answer (score 0):

There are abstractions for that in [ActionDispatch::Reloader](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Reloader.html) : it's what's used in development environment to reload classes.

So basically, you would need to run :

```
ActionDispatch::Reloader.cleanup!
ActionDispatch::Reloader.prepare!
```

I'm not sure it would be such a good idea, though, as you can't expect which code (yours or from gems) does things that are supposed to happen only once.

Couldn't you use [STI](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance) rather than dynamicly creating tables ?

Comment: Hi Mekki Thanks for your comment, please let me know where i should include the above statments.