# Symbol table overflow run time error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running my application which is developed using Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.8 and MySQL 5.1 in development environment as i have problem with `config.cache_classes` in production environment.

Application is running fine, but after a day or two i am getting `symbol table over flow` run time error. After restarting the server then the application is running as usual.

Can any body help me out why this symbol table overflow run time error is coming and how to resolve it.

Comment: set config.cache_classes = true in your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you mistakenly leave class caching disabled in production.

Your rails config/environments/production.rb should have:

`config.cache_classes = true`

Thanks

Comment: config.cache_classes = true, is giving problem in my application, Please find the problem description at link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784730/clearing-rails-cache-dynamically